# Getting true video Height/Width from ASF videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, resolution, asf

I am trying to convert an ASF video with FFmpeg using an interface called mediahandler.

The issue is, the metadata on the ASF video appears to be corrupt. It states that the video is 640x240, and 4:3 aspect ratio.

The aspect ratio is correct, but obviously the resolution is not. This causes the converter to incorrectly scale the video, because it uses the resolution to determine the original aspect ratio.

I am able to get the aspect ratio metadata, but I'm not sure this solves the issue, because I would think that if the resolution could be incorrect, then so could the aspect ratio metadata.

So, is there any way to get the actual height/width? It appears that players like VLC have no issue with this. How do I do such a thing w/ FFmpeg?